# How to specify buffer local variables for the edit buffer of org source blocks?

Tags: org-babel

Consider the following org-file.

```org
#+NAME: example-src-block
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defun my-message ()
  "Issue my message."
  (message "Within the emacs-lisp source block."))
#+END_SRC
```

How can the buffer local setting

```el
(setq-local flycheck-disabled-checkers '(emacs-lisp-checkdoc))
```

be specified for the edit buffer of source block `example-src-block`.

Note: For opening the edit buffer place point on `BEGIN_SRC` and press <kbd>C-c '</kbd>.

The user [J. Ricardo](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/16462/j-ricardo) tried in a deleted question the following approach:

```org
#+NAME: example-src-block
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(and (boundp 'flycheck-disabled-checkers)
     flycheck-disabled-checkers)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: example-src-block
| emacs-lisp-checkdoc |

# Local Variables:
# eval: (setq-local org-babel-default-header-args:elisp '((:var . "flycheck-disabled-checkers='(emacs-lisp-checkdoc)")))
# End:
```

That does not set `flycheck-disabled-checkers` in **source edit buffers** for the source block.
It only sets `flycheck-disabled-checkers` for the **evaluation** of the source block. as the printed result of the source block in the above example suggests.

Comment: @j-ricardo You deleted your question really fast. I think your question was really of general interest! You are absolutely right. An org buffer is like a directory for its source blocks. Why shouldn't we have "file variables" for the source blocks and "directory local" variables for the org buffer in the figurative sense? I am very sorry if I motivated you to delete your question with my comment. That was not my intention! Maybe your question only needed a (very) small bit of re-work. I tried to re-formulate it here and hope that I hit your actual problem with it. I added also my solution...

Answer (score 2):

Put `(add-hook 'org-src-mode-hook 'hack-local-variables)` into your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).
This enables the automatic evaluation of buffer local variables when you edit org source blocks with `org-edit-src-code`. You specify the buffer local variables for source blocks in the same manner as [file local variables for files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).

See the following example for a source block in an org file. The characters `^L` actually stand for an inserted form-feed character. That character avoids that the buffer local variables for the source block are interpreted as file local variables for the org-file.

```org
#+NAME: example-src-block
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(and (boundp 'flycheck-disabled-checkers)
     flycheck-disabled-checkers)
# Local Variables:
# flycheck-disabled-checkers: (emacs-lisp-checkdoc)
# End:
#+END_SRC

^L
```

---

The above solution still does not yet set buffer local variables for **all** elisp source blocks in an org file as [J. Ricardo](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/16462/j-ricardo) attempted to do.

For that purpose one can introduce a new header argument `:edit-prep-form` for emacs-lisp source blocks with help of the following function. That function can also be defined in your init file.

```el
(defun org-babel-edit-prep:emacs-lisp (info)
  "Add parsing of :edit-prep-form for emacs-lisp source blocks."
  (let* ((header-argument-alist (nth 2 info))
     (edit-prep-form (assoc :edit-prep-form header-argument-alist)))
    (when edit-prep-form
      (eval (cdr edit-prep-form)))))
```

With that function installed a similar approach as that one proposed by [J. Ricardo](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/16462/j-ricardo) works. The only difference is that the header argument `:var` needs to be replaced by `:edit-prep-form`.

```org
#+NAME: example-src-block
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
  (and (boundp 'flycheck-disabled-checkers)
       flycheck-disabled-checkers)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: example-src-block

# Local Variables:
# org-babel-default-header-args:emacs-lisp: ((:edit-prep-form . (setq-local flycheck-disabled-checkers '(emacs-lisp-checkdoc))))
# End:
```

---

The last approach works for source blocks with one certain language.
The following elisp code adds a hook variable `org-edit-src-code-hook`.
Hook functions added buffer-locally within the org buffer to that hook variable
are run in all newly generated source edit buffers for source blocks of that org buffer.

```el
(defvar org-edit-src-code-hook nil
  "Hook run after the setup of the edit buffer for an org source block.
The hook functions added buffer-locally within the org buffer
are run in the source edit buffers for the source blocks within the org file.")

(defun org-edit-src-code-hook-run (return-value)
  "Run `org-edit-src-code-hook' after `org-edit-src-code' with non-nil RETURN-VALUE."
  (when (and return-value
         (buffer-live-p (org-src--source-buffer)))
    (let ((hook-value (with-current-buffer (org-src--source-buffer)
            org-edit-src-code-hook)))
      (cl-loop for local-hook in hook-value
           if (eq local-hook t) do
           (cl-loop for global-hook in (default-value 'org-edit-src-code-hook) do
            (funcall global-hook))
           else do (funcall local-hook))))
  return-value)

(advice-add 'org-edit-src-code :filter-return #'org-edit-src-code-hook-run)
```

In the following org file we add buffer-locally an anonymous hook function to `org-edit-src-code-hook` that prints out the current buffer.

```org
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results silent
(message "Running source block.")
#+END_SRC

# Local Variables:
# eval: (add-hook 'org-edit-src-code-hook (lambda () (message "Local src code hook for current buffer: %S" (current-buffer))) nil t)
# End:
```